# How do I save multiple histograms to different (separate) files?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to save a bunch of histograms as images. And this is what I did so far.

```
for i in range(len(images)):
    histogram, bin_edges = np.histogram(images[i].ravel(), 256, [0, 256])
    plt.plot(histogram)
    plt.show()
```

Output of the above code:

[image: Output of the above code]

This output is fine, but I want to save these as images.

I used plt.savefig() but this isn't the result I'm looking for.

```
for i in range(len(images)):
    histogram, bin_edges = np.histogram(images[i].ravel(), 256, [0, 256])
    plt.plot(histogram)
    plt.savefig("histograms/hist_frame"+str(count)+".png")
    count+=1
```

Output of the above code:

[image: output of the above code.]

How do I save these histograms in separate files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is plotting every histogram on the same figure, In order to have multiple figures, you need to create a new figure for each plot:

```
for i in range(len(images)):
  plt.figure()
  histogram, bin_edges = np.histogram(images[i].ravel(), 256, [0, 256])
  plt.plot(histogram)
  plt.savefig("histograms/hist_frame"+str(count)+".png")
  count+=1
```

Note that if showing the plot, `plt.show()` should follow `plt.savefig()`, otherwise the file image will be blank.